# How to get the pintf output from a cdll .so file in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, .so

I use a `cdll` module to load a C library in Python, which just like:

```
from ctypes import cdll 

LIBRARY = "./foo.so"

cdll.LoadLibrary(LIBRARY.encode())
```

And in this library, its function will print some info to the output(I guess  it's the stdout).

So the problem is **'how to get the output from the C library ?' And I can use it as a Python String**

Comment: First you need to capture the return value from the `LoadLibrary`, which you are not doing, then you call the function as a method on that value.  Do you have to pass any parameters to the function?  It will probably return a bytes object by the way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, what I write is just an example. In my script I do all things that you said. But what I want is to get the output of printf() function in a C library. Not just the return code '1'. In another word, the C library code does not return what I want. It just prints its out. So I need to get the output.

Comment: Please post your expected output. Your actual output. And your code producing it. Guesses are to be ignored. "the output from a C library" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have never tried this with a C DLL, but in theory the DLL will be using the same `stdout` as Python because it is running in the same process. So you might be able to use `sys.stdout  = StringIO()` before the calls then use the `StringIO` methods to get the text.  Not sure if that will work, but it might be worth a try.